# Saving the position of items in the Sortable component

Tags: javascript, getuikit

I'm using UIKit (GetUIKit) within Vue.js. I have 3 lists of objects (id, picture) that I drag across. I would like to save the position of the pictures in each list but the arrays don't seem to have changed and I don't know how to find which array it has be dropped into.

```
<template>
  <div class="uk-child-width-1-4@s" uk-grid>
    <div>
      <h4>Selected products</h4>
      <div
        uk-sortable="group: sortable-group"
        v-for="product in selectedProducts"
        v-bind:key="product.id"
        v-on:stop="greet(product.id, selectedProducts, outfit1, outfit2)"
      >
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-small uk-card-default uk-card-body">
          <img v-bind:src="product.image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4>Outfit 1</h4>
      <div
        uk-sortable="group: sortable-group"
        v-for="product in outfit1"
        v-bind:key="product.id"
        v-on:stop="greet(product.id, selectedProducts, outfit1, outfit2)
      >
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-small uk-card-default uk-card-body">
          <img v-bind:src="product.image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4>Outfit 2</h4>
      <div
        uk-sortable="group: sortable-group"
        v-for="product in outfit2"
        v-bind:key="product.id"
        v-on:stop="greet(product.id, selectedProducts, outfit1, outfit2)"
      >
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-small uk-card-default uk-card-body">
          <img v-bind:src="product.image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedProducts: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Cool top",
          image:
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfpwfhIA_q8BvD5Hj6TKHfTd0fhfaNQcYKPlBcww6aZXWUOE3R"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Fun jeans",
          image:
            "https://wwws.dior.com/couture/ecommerce/media/catalog/product/cache/1/grid_image_8/460x497/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/U/d/1550571393_922P02A3932_X5846_E08_GH.jpg"
        }
      ],
      outfit1: [
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "shoes",
          image: "https://images.vans.com/is/image/Vans/D3HY28-HERO?$583x583$"
        }
      ],
      outfit2: [
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "scarf",
          image:
            "https://www.brontebymoon.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/TAR80-A01-Lambswool-Tartan-Scarf-Antique-Dress-Stewart.jpg"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    greet: function(position, ) {
      // This is where I want to save the position, for ex: {outfit1: [id: 1,2], outfit2: [id: 3], selectedProduct: [id: 4]}
      console.log(position);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I want to save the position, for ex: `{outfit1: [id: 1,2], outfit2: [id: 3], selectedProduct: [id: 4]}` but I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Provide the example of current positioning.

Comment: you have methods for sortable so maybe you want to save the position on `moved` event

Comment: Hey @moped thank you! Where can I find the methods? I try to find them on the UIkit documentation but they weren’t very helpful

Comment: check my answer here, it may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47549648/uikit-how-to-get-order-with-the-sortable-component/47558397#47558397